# Как вызвать статический метод внутри класса? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Мне нужно вызвать статический метод при объявлении атрибута класса, но следующий код выдает ошибку.

```
class Test():
    dict = {
        'a': Test.func(1),
        'b': Test.func(2),
        'c': Test.func(3),
    }
    @staticmethod
    def func(num):
        return num*2
```

> ```
> 'a': Test.func(1),
> NameError: name 'Test' is not defined
> ```

Comment: Покажите как вы вызов делаете

Comment: @Александр 'a': Test.func(1)

Answer (score 3):

Оборачивайте, например, исполняемый код в лямбды:

```
class Test:
    dict_ = {
        'a': lambda: Test.func(1),
        'b': lambda: Test.func(2),
        'c': lambda: Test.func(3),
    }
    @staticmethod
    def func(num):
        return num * 2


print(Test.dict_['a']())
# 2
```

Answer (score 1):

как вариант:

```
def func(num):
    return num * 2

class Test():
    def __init__(self):                                   
        super().__init__()
        
        self.dict_ = {
            'a': func(1),
            'b': func(2),
            'c': func(3),
        }

test = Test()

a = test.dict_['a']
b = test.dict_['b']
c = test.dict_['c']
print(f'a = {a}, b = {b}, c = {c}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test():
    
    @staticmethod
    def func(num):
        return num*2

    dict_ = {
        'a': func.__func__(1),
        'b': func.__func__(2),
        'c': func.__func__(3),
    }

print(Test.dict_['a'], Test.dict_['b'], Test.dict_['c'])
```

Вывод:

```
2 4 6
```

Вариант решения [подсмотрен здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41921291/8324991)